# Papaya plant is getting insects

Tags: houseplants, pests, pest-control, insects, papaya

I have small papaya plant in my balcony. I had two plants in my balcony. One of which was the smaller one died after lots of white insects on that. Now I can see some insects on other plant as well. Please suggest how to remove it. 
I am located in west part of India.And whether is around 35 degree with bright sun.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good photo, very helpful. This looks like mealybugs which are a known problem on papaya in India. There is [a wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracoccus_marginatus) and there are many pages describing remedies. The big problem for home gardeners is that there are many host plants which can be sources of continuous infection; you may control it for now but they will be back very soon. If you only have one or a couple of plants and are looking for entertainment you can very frequently inspect and remove with a cotton swab with isopropyl alcohol, but if you are successful papaya can grow large and it will be an increasing problem.

Comment: I tried to swab with cotton, and it went for 1-2 days but yes it back again. But I can see some big plants of Papaya successfully giving fruits in garden very near to balcony. Isn't this issue occur to that.